# Why the video in the chrome page is not working?

Tags: html, google-chrome, video

So I am new to HTML and I am working on Visual Studio Code. I am currently trying to make a page that has a video on it. I made a simple code that I thought would work but it doesn't. After entering the page you see the video player but the video is not playing. The name of the video is bodybuild.mp4 and is located in videos.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Video_page_test</title>
</head>
<body>
<video controls>
    <source src = "videos/bodybuild.mp4" type = "video/mp4">

</video>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you check the console of your browser? Are there any errors there?

Comment: There are no errors.

Comment: This code should work fine. We'll need more information to be able to help you. What do you mean by "the video is not playing"? What _is_ happening? Did you click the play button?

Comment: Indeed the play button was clicked. The video was loading for 1 second then stopped. If needed I can make a screenshot.

Comment: That _sounds_ as if the file could not be loaded, but that should also add an error to your console. Could you make a screenshot of the console?

Comment: I took the screenshots.

Comment: You're showing the console of VS Code, not of your browser. See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/open/ Your script will look for a `/videos` folder in the same folder as where your `test.html` file is and within that `/videos` folder it will look for a file `bodybuild.mp4`. I'm assuming that your `/videos` folder and `test.html` file are not both in the same folder.

Comment: I looked into the console. It said: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: @DiligentPD Please run the command `tree` in your vs code terminal and show us what the result is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. Try using an **absolute path** (ie: `C:/user/videos/video.mp4`)

Or

2. Put the `videos` folder in same place as your HTML file before testing in a web browser 
    (double click the HTML file in Explorer, not just running HTML via debugger/IDE).

Comment: @DiligentPD the video tag would also work if **your html file is running from** `C:/user/` since the HTML can look around its location (which is `C:/user/`) and find that there is a `videos` sub-folder... **To test**:  Put your HTML file in `c:\user\ ` then add a folder there called `videos` (with mp4 file) then finally code like `/videos/bodybuild.mp4` will work okay to play the video...

Comment: @DiligentPD Presumably it will work on your local machine. However, if you host it on another machine, it will not work as expected. So relative path is usually the way to go.